# OSM search Address or GeoPoint

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap, graphhopper

I search for the solution, search address in OSMdroid or Graphhopper.
Have any body a tipp what i can search or looking for.

I use:
-OSMdroid
-Graphhopper
-Android

Comment: The keyword you are looking for is *geocoding*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OSMBonusPack: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack, this bonus pack contains reverse geocoding!

Check here the documentation
https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/features#geocoding-and-reverse-geocoding

Comment: no problem! if this helps you, please mark it as "accepted"

Comment: just to clarify: geocoding is address into coordinates. reverse geocoding is coordinates into address. I think OP searches for geocoding.

Comment: In this bonus pack there are both :)